# 503 error while using request while using request module

Tags: django, python-requests, python-3.7

i am trying to get the response from a http web request, when i tried to enter the same url over the website it asked for user name and password, and it returned json after entering the user name and password, but next time it was directly fetching the json.

Next i tried to get the response from requests.get in python django

```
url = 'https://employee-dev.comserver/worker/Course&$format=json'
r=requests.get(url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('system', 'system123'),verify=False)
```

when i tried to print the r.error_code its printing 503. How do i resolve it? let me know if you need more debug information

Comment: when I hit `https://employee-dev.comserver/worker/Course&$format=json` it isn't reachable. Is your URL correct? 503 also suggests that the server is down or at least not able to respond

Comment: HI Jonas, it is reachable over chrome website. i have given a dummy url.. first time hitting will ask user name and password but second time it will go smooth. but not able to connect from python script